# What is the difference between these?

Tags: c++, pointers, dictionary

Can anyone please explain me the difference about the below used methods to insert a new object in the map container? I already know about pointers and such, I'm not really deep into virtual memory, only the basics (addresses etc..)

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class CUser
{
public:
    CUser() { Init(); };
    ~CUser() {};
public:
        BOOL m_bActive;
        BOOL m_bLoggedIn;
        SYSTEMTIME m_sysTime;

        void Init();
};


void CUser::Init()
{
    (*this).m_bActive = FALSE;
    m_bLoggedIn = FALSE;
    GetSystemTime( &m_sysTime );
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    map<DWORD, CUser*>mUserMap;


    //what is the difference between this
    {   
        CUser pUser;
        pUser.m_bActive = FALSE;
        pUser.m_bLoggedIn = FALSE;
        GetSystemTime( &pUser.m_sysTime );
        mUserMap.insert( make_pair( 351, &pUser ) );
    }
    //and this?
    {
        CUser *pUser = new CUser;
        if( pUser )
        {
            pUser->m_bActive = TRUE;
            pUser->m_bLoggedIn = TRUE;
            GetSystemTime( &pUser->m_sysTime );
            mUserMap.insert( make_pair( 351, pUser ) );
        }
    }

/*  map<DWORD, CUser*>::iterator it = mUserMap.find( 351 );
    if( it == mUserMap.end() )
        std::cout << "Not found" << std::endl;
    else
    {
        CUser *pUser = it->second;
        if( pUser )
            std::cout << pUser->m_sysTime.wHour << std::endl;
    } */


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//what is the difference between this
{   
    CUser pUser;
    pUser.m_bActive = FALSE;
    pUser.m_bLoggedIn = FALSE;
    GetSystemTime( &pUser.m_sysTime );
    mUserMap.insert( make_pair( 351, &pUser ) );
}
```

this creates a local object: your `pUser` variable only exists *inside* the scope of this block, and ceases to exist when the last `}` is reached. That means its destructor is called, and the memory it lived in is reclaimed and may be reused.

Now, when you store a pointer to this short-lived object in your map, you're storing a problem.  If you de-reference that pointer at any time after the closing `}` of this block, you're invoking undefined behaviour.  It may work.  It may work sometimes, and then start to fail.  Basically, it's a logical error and a good source of unpredictable bugs.

```
//and this?
{
    CUser *pUser = new CUser;
    if( pUser )
    {
        pUser->m_bActive = TRUE;
        pUser->m_bLoggedIn = TRUE;
        GetSystemTime( &pUser->m_sysTime );
        mUserMap.insert( make_pair( 351, pUser ) );
    }
}
```

here you explicitly create an instance which will outlive the enclosing scope, and all is good.  You don't need to check if `new` returns `NULL` though: it'll throw an exception unless you explicitly request it not to.

Answer (score 4):

In the first case, `pUser` is created on the stack, and will automatically be deleted when its name goes out of scope (i.e. at the next closing curly bracket). Generally speaking, it's unwise to insert pointers to stack objects into containers, because the object will cease to exist while the container still have a value pointing to it. This can cause a crash in the best case. In the worst case, it could cause erratic and hard to locate bugs in distant parts of the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
{   
    CUser pUser;
    pUser.m_bActive = FALSE;
    pUser.m_bLoggedIn = FALSE;
    GetSystemTime( &pUser.m_sysTime );
    mUserMap.insert( make_pair( 351, &pUser ) );
}
//pUser is not available here
```

pUser (Object) unavailable (deleted), pointer in mUserMap is invalid!

```
{
    CUser *pUser = new CUser;
    if( pUser )
    {
        pUser->m_bActive = TRUE;
        pUser->m_bLoggedIn = TRUE;
        GetSystemTime( &pUser->m_sysTime );
        mUserMap.insert( make_pair( 351, pUser ) );
    }
}
//pUser is not available here
```

pUser (Pointer!!) unavailable (deleted), memory is still claimed so pointer in mUserMapis valid!

Comment: Wow guys thank you a lot!! I had no idea there were so many persons ready to help! I'll keep on posting my questions looking forward to be expert as you guys are. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 1):

The difference is here is that the object created by the call to `new` is created on the heap and not the stack. This means that once the pointer goes out of scope, the memory allocated is still in existence on the heap and you can safely reference it through the pointer stored in your map.

In the first case, you create an object on the stack and add its address to the map. This means that when your locally created variable goes out of scope it is destroyed and the pointer in your map now points to a variable that is no longer in existence. This will undoubtedly lead to problems in your code.

Use the first approach if you must use pointers and not actual objects themselves.
When you use `new` the memory will persist until you delete it (or get another object to take care of it like a shared pointer). Stack objects are destroyed as soon as they go out of scope.